# How to print entity referenced fields (node) title in node.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I want to print an entity referenced fields (node) title in `node--customtype.tpl.php`.

`<?php print render($content['field_my_entity_reference']); ?>` prints the field with some CSS class as below:

```
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">
<a href="/node/11">Entity Title</a>
</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to print this field **without any pre-defined CSS classes etc.**.

```
[field_my_entity_reference] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [target_id] => 11
                            [entity] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [vid] => 41
                                    [uid] => 1
                                    [title] => Entity Title
                                    [log] => 
                                    [status] => 1
                                    [comment] => 1
                                    [promote] => 0
                                    [sticky] => 0
                                    [nid] => 11
                                    [type] => project
                                    [language] => es
                                    [created] => 1466009429
                                    [changed] => 1466502663
                                    [tnid] => 0
                                    [translate] => 0
                                    [revision_timestamp] => 1466502663
                                    [revision_uid] => 1
                                    [body] => Array
                                        (
                                            [und] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [value] =>
```

I tried `<?php print $node->field_my_entity_reference['und'][0]['entity']['title']; ?>` but it gives error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

### How can I print the title value of entity referenced field in node.tpl.php?

Comment: You can actually print the reference entity using `print render($content['field_machine_name']);`.

Comment: My bad..see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, without knowing anything about `stdClass Object` these kind of questions are normal :)

So, after reading [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168422/how-to-access-a-property-of-an-object-stdclass-object-member-element-of-an-arr) about stdClass Object in SO I did what I want as below:

```
<?php print $node->field_my_entity_reference['und'][0]['entity']->title; ?>
```

This prints the title as plain text.

*Note: Is there another way or better way you're always welcome.*

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using the API is to use `field_get_items` and `field_view_value`.

Consider this example:

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_machine_name');
$title = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_machine_name', $field[0]);
print render($title);
```

`$title` will produce...

```
Array
(
    [#markup] => test lang
    [#access] => 1
)
```

which is a renderable array.

The advantage of this against `print $node->field_my_entity_reference['und'][0]['entity']->title;` is the API will take care of the translation.

If you want to still use `print $node->field_my_entity_reference['und'][0]['entity']->title` I advice to avoid using `und` instead I will use`LANGUAGE_NONE` or much better `$node->language`.

```
print $node->field_my_entity_reference[$node->language][0]['entity']->title;
```

Comment: It is the most elegant way.